# Count New Users Group in Tableau

Tags: calculation, tableau-api

These are the fields that I have
Dimension: **Usertype**, when you filter I have "New Visitor" "Returning Visitor"
Measure: **users** - sum of both new & returning visitors

How can I create the calculation that will count only **New Visitors** inside the **users** measure pill without using the filter option?

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering answer is:
usertype - dimension (New Visitor, Returning Visitor)
users - measure (Total of both New Visitor and Returning Visitor)

MIN({FIXED [usertype]='New Visitor': SUM([users])})

Answer (score 0):

An alternate, possibly more efficient, approach is to define a calculated field that incorporates your filter. Say define a calculated field called, **New Users**, as

```
IF [Usertype] = “New Visitor” THEN [Users] END
```

(This field will evaluate to null if the [Usertype] <> “New Visitor”)

If you then place SUM([New Users]) on some shelf, you’ll have your result - without the complexity of an LOD calculation. LOD calcs are incredibly useful, but they add complexity and performance cost, so I’d recommend using them only when needed. In many cases, such as this, simpler methods work fine.